# Get the immediate parent of child node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I want to retrieve the parent of the `child node` without clicking on the `tree`..

```
data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj).attr("id");
```

Above command give me the immediate parent when we click on the `child nodes`.

Is there a way to get the `parent node` without clicking on the `child node`.

Regards,
Praque M

Comment: You can use .parent() and .parents() function of jQuery to get the parent object.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the "data.inst" was renamed in newer versions to "data.instance". This made tracking down the solution difficult

`data.instance.get_parent(data.node)` returns the string ID of the parent (much unexpected for me). To get the parent I had to call `data.instance.get_node()` on the string ID.

`data.instance.get_parent(data.node)` is also accessible thru data.node.parent.

Example:

```
$('#MaterialCollectionTree').on('activate_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
  if(data.instance.is_leaf(data.node)) {
    alert("Leaf: " + data.node.text);
    alert("Parent: " +  data.instance.get_node(data.node.parent).text);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit more complex then that

```
parent_node = $.jstree._reference('#tree_id')._get_parent(n);
```

The variable parent_node is a jquery object so the command

```
parent_node.attr("something");
```

is the same as

```
$("#parent_node_id").attr("something");
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone here looking for just the parent id for a particular node at any moment(without an event firing: like without a selection) and if you have the node id easiest way to do so is:

```
$('#your_tree_id').jstree().get_parent($("#your_node_id"));
```

(replace 'your_tree_id' with your tree's id and your_node_id with your node's id)

Comment: This is simple and it works great.