# How to get parent and parent's parent id in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm creating a jstree in my program. Now I'm able to get the checked node id. But how can I get the id of the parent node id and also the parent's parent node id.

[image]

Below is my javascript to get the children node id.

```js
 $('#tree-container').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                var i, j, r = [];
                for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
                    r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id.trim());
                }
                //alert('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
                console.log('Selected: ' + r.join(', '));
   

            });
```

Here is my jsfddle. Please take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/jjfcnho8/2/ When i select Child 9, I can get child 9 id. Then how can I get Child 2 and folder 1 id.

Anyone know please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Write your demo on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) or something else... and check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14219662/3281415), it could be a duplicate

Comment: I have view that answer before but it can only help me get the parent node id only. I can't get the parent's parent node id

Comment: As I said, build your example code on plunker then we can help you easier.

Comment: Add fiddle or plunker demo

Comment: I'm creating...Wait ya

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jjfcnho8/2/ Here is my jsfiddle. Pls take a look

Comment: @SerCrAsH I can get the child 9 id but can't get the child 2 and folder 1 id

Comment: But if when I select child 9 and child 10, then only I can get the child 2 id

Comment: Use `data.node.parents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `parents` property of the node object you get from `data.instance.get_node()`. As several nodes could have the same ancestor, you'd maybe want to avoid gathering duplicates. For this you can use a `Set`. This is just one way you could do it:

```
var nodesOnSelectedPath = [...data.selected.reduce(function (acc, nodeId) {
    var node = data.instance.get_node(nodeId);
    return new Set([...acc, ...node.parents, node.id]);
}, new Set)];

console.log('Selected: ' + nodesOnSelectedPath.join(', '));
```

Note that this will include the root node as well, which has id '#'.

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjfcnho8/3/).

#### Without the root node

To get the list without the `#`, it is the easiest to apply a filter on the result:

```
console.log('Selected: ' + nodesOnSelectedPath.filter(id => id !== '#').join(', '));
```

#### EcmaScript2015

The above scripts use features from EcmaScript2015 (ES6). Some editors may highlight syntax errors when they are not configured to recognise ES6 syntax. [Here](http://moritz.berlin/writes/2015/adding-the-ecmascript-6-flavour-to-your-ide/) you can find how to configure VSCode, Sublime Text, and WebStorm for ES6.

#### ES5 Alternative

In ES5 you would use an object (`acc`) to collect unique id references as property names. Although `Object.keys` is really ES6, it is often supported in otherwise ES5 browsers:

```
var nodesOnSelectedPath = Object.keys(data.selected.reduce(function (acc, nodeId) {
    var node = data.instance.get_node(nodeId);
    node.parents.forEach(function (id) {
        acc[id] = 1;
    });
    acc[node.id] = 1;
    return acc;
}, {}));
```

Here is the corresponding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjfcnho8/7/).

#### Circular references in data

You wrote in comments that you tried to do this:

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

But that data structure has parent and child references in it, so it is possible to go from a child to its parent object, and from there back to its child object, ... which is endless. Such structures cannot be converted to JSON. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) for solutions.

Comment: Thanks For your answer and I have some question to ask. 
1) nodesOnSelectedPath = [...data.selected.reduce(function (acc, nodeId) {
        var node = data.instance.get_node(nodeId);
        return new Set([...acc, ...node.parents, node.id]);
    }, new Set)]; << This line show syntax error at my coding. But when I running, it still can run successfully. Why this will happen?

Comment: 2)console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); << This line make me got this error. Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.. Only when I deleted this line, program only can run

Comment: 3)How can i deleted the root node id ? Thank you

Comment: I'm using this way to remove #.  

var itemtoRemove = "#";    nodesOnSelectedPath.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove,nodesOnSelectedPath),1);

Comment: Question 2 really is another question, and there are a lot of answers about that on SO. Anyway, I added an answer for all three follow-up questions in my answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Really Learnt a lot of thing. Anyway, thanks again

Comment: Thanks, this is (almost) working for me too, except that I get a `TypeError: data.selected.reduce(...).delete(...) is not iterable` if I put the `.delete('#')` part... please, any help?

Comment: Indeed, it does not work with `.delete()` (this was a too-quick addition I made). Use `.filter` on the result instead. See update in answer.

Comment: Sorry to come again on this :-( please can you post a non-EC6 version of this script?

Comment: I added an "ES5 Alternative" section to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can find parent element by this method

```
obj.parent();
```

or

```
obj.parent(expr); //expr is a filter express
```

Comment: Can u pls explain more? I have try obj also. but it show "cannot  read property 'obj' of undefined....".

Comment: It is _very_ unlikely that the DOM parent is the same as the parent node within the tree itself

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by getting `this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id` in the onclick even of the jstree object.

example:

```
$('#myjstree').jstree({<your jstree parameters>}).on('click', '.jstree-anchor', function (e) {
if (this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id == 'id_im_looking_for')
        alert('Yup GOT IT!') 
});
```

Tested this with jstree v3.2 using an html data source. A bit wonky? yes. Definitely test after upgrades to the jstree library because if the library developers change this structure of the nodes the example provided will no longer work.